# Set default value for number in NumberPicker

Tags: java, android, string, math

Im trying to do some simple math with number pickers, This is basic string manipulation is all. Just having troubles find a start in the code below. I have several number pickers, Each one has a predetermined value to each interval within.

`NumberPicker np - adds 25 to each individual number. 1 = 25, 2 = 50, etc`

`NumberPicker np2 - adds 100 to each individual number. 1 = 100, 2 = 200, etc`

Now i have a main TextView that i had to display the current output of these number pickers values added with there "weight" to them and display the added up number.

My apologies if my question is not as clear as im trying to write it, I'm just having troubles finding good resources to help me figure out how to do this in a easy way.

Im trying to in the below code, get the current value of my textview, then get the value of the numberpicker, Then i need code to add the number 25, so 1 = +25, then set it to my textview.

```
    String current_weight = current_weight_view.getText().toString();
String newvalue= getText(newVal).toString(); 
    res=Integer.parseInt(current_weight)+Integer.parseInt(newvalue);
current_weight_view.setText(Integer.toString(res));
```

--

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private TextView current_weight;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupUI();
    }
    public void setupUI()
    {
        current_weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_weight);
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId);
        NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.NumberPicker01);
        NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.NumberPicker02);
        NumberPicker np3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.NumberPicker03);


        np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                current_weight.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
            }        
        });
        np1.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                current_weight.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
            }        
        });
        np2.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                current_weight.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
            }        
        });
        np3.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                current_weight.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
            }        
        });

        np.setMaxValue(10);
        np.setMinValue(1);
        np1.setMaxValue(10);
        np1.setMinValue(1);
        np2.setMaxValue(10);
        np2.setMinValue(1);
        np3.setMaxValue(10);
        np3.setMinValue(1);
    }
```

Comment: `np.setValue(int v)` won't do ?

Comment: @user117 using `np45.setValue(5);` simply sets the default value to be 5, now i need code to make that 1 equals 10, so if the value was 5 it would be a number of 10 x 5 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve,May be you can try [`NumberPicker.Formatter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.Formatter.html) :

```
 np.setMaxValue(10);
 np.setMinValue(1);

 np.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int i) {
            return String.valueOf(i*10);
        }
 });
```

Now `NumberPicker` will show values as 10,20,30..100 instead of 1,2,3..10. However internally values will not change, if user selects 100, `getValue()` will be 10.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code, This is SOOO close to have im trying to do, However more on the opposite side... I still want the values 1 through 10 to display. However when user selects 1 i have it to add lets say (i+10); then display on the textview 10, if user selects 5 then is will display 50, Does that make sense?